# How to let Jupyter pick a different IRkernel?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

I had problems with the anaconda R (especially installing packages lately caused a problem I could not solve where any attempt to install a package led to non-zero exiting status). Installing a separate R distribution and let Rstudio pick that one and not the one given by anaconda solved all problems for the last months.

Now I want to work with Jupyter and also use nteract or hydrogen from Atom. However, Jupyter uses the R from anaconda and so does then nteract/hydrogen. Therefore, I have the problem again being unable to install 75% of the packages for unknown reasons. I could of course try to find the cause of that BUT I also invested hours into that so I think the easiest/fastest way is to let Jupyter pick the same R that Rstudio uses since I have a fully working environment there...

Can anybody please explain to me how I can make jupyter pick the IRkernel that I installed in Rstudio instead of the anaconda IRkernel? Just deleting the anaconda kernel did not work of course. I also tried `IRkernel::installspec()` as suggested by the docs.

Answer (score 0):

After deleting the Anaconda R, I had to run R in the terminal and run this:

```
install.packages(c('repr', 'IRdisplay', 'evaluate', 'crayon', 'pbdZMQ', 'devtools', 'uuid', 'digest'))
devtools::install_github('IRkernel/IRkernel', force=T)
IRkernel::installspec()
```

Then it worked.